# Arguments of function inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create some objects but don't know how to write the arguments of a function inside another function. Here is code with comments to explain better.

```
function Troop(rss, time, offense, defense){    
  this.rss= rss;
  this.time= time;
  this.offense= offense;
  this.defense= function types(a, b, c, d){ 
    this.a= a;
    this.b= b;
    this.c= c;
    this.d= d;
  } 
}
   Dwarf = new Troop(1,2,3, new types(11,22,33,44));   // this most be wrong
   alert(Dwarf.defense.a) // how can I access to the values after?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `types` to be its own function, then you can just pass in the object to the `Troop` constructor.

```
function types(a, b, c, d) {
    this.a= a;
    this.b= b;
    this.c= c;
    this.d= d;
}

function Troop(rss, time, offense, defense){    
  this.rss= rss;
  this.time= time;
  this.offense= offense;
  this.defense= defense;
}

Dwarf = new Troop(1,2,3, new types(11,22,33,44));   // these lines are right
alert(Dwarf.defense.a) // it's the function definition that was wrong :)
```

In general I would capitalize the class names like `Types`, and keep the variables like `dwarf` lower-case, but that's more just a question of style, not functionality.

Comment: I thought about it, but then the last 2 lines are right? will they work?

Comment: Yep, they work just fine as you had them. I couldn't help changing the case of Types, but the only real change I made was breaking `types` out to a separate function. Don't define it inside of `Troop`.  I just reverted my style suggestions so as not to muddy the issue.